# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n \log n}{n!}$ a positive sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The below series is convergent series by the ratio test but i'm no able to know if this series have a positive sum , and i don't succeed to check if it has a closed form ,Then my question here is :

> **Question:**
>   Is this : $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n \log n}{n!}$ a positive sum ?

Comment: It is fast convergent series, so it is enough to estimate few first terms.

Comment: [The alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) comes with an estimate for the error. That should be enough to establish the sign of the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n \geq 2$, the expression $\frac{\log n}{n!}$ is strictly decreasing, as $\frac{\log (n+1)}{(n+1)!} < \frac{\log n}{n!} \iff \log (n+1) < (n+1) \log n \iff \log_n (n+1) < n+1$, which is true, because $\log_n (n+1) < \log_n (n^2) = 2$. Therefore, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \log n}{n!}$$ is an alternating series with terms that strictly decrease in magnitude after the first nonzero term, so the series has the same sign as the first nonzero term, which is positive.

Answer (score 1):

> -*Teacher, what is the best way for dealing with series with oscillating terms?
>
>   -To invoke the Laplace transform, of course.*

Since $\log(n)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-nx}}{x}\,dx $ by Frullani's theorem, by multiplying both sides by $\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$ and summing over $n\geq 1$ we have:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n \log(n)}{n!} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\color{blue}{1+e^{-x-1}-e^{-x}-e^{-e^{-x}}}}{x}\,dx $$
where it is tedious, but fairly simple, to check that the blue term is positive for any $x>0$.
It follows that the LHS is positive as well. Additionally, since the integrand function in the RHS behaves like $\left(1-\frac{2}{e}\right)\exp\left[-\frac{(e-1)}{2(e-2)}x\right]$ in a right neighbourhood of the origin, the value of the LHS is approximately $\frac{2(e-2)^2}{e(e-1)}\approx 0.22$.

---

Actually this trick works best for checking the sign of slowly convergent, oscillating series. Here the term $\frac{\log(n)}{n!}$ goes to zero incredibly fast, so it is not really needed, as already shown by Connor Harris above.